# How to expand div height to content with ruby each-loop in rails?

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having trouble expanding the height of this div. When I shrink the window height or look at the same page from a mobile device, half of the content is cut out. I have tried height: 100% and min-height: 100% and used vh and overflow: auto, nothing works.

```
<div class="col-md-9 c-center">
      <div id="grid-container-fullwidth" class="cbp cbp-caption-active cbp-ready processed cbp-caption-zoom cbp-cols-3 c-left" style="height:1270px">
        <div class="cbp-wrapper-outer"><div class="cbp-wrapper">
          <div style="height: 100%">

            <% @companies.each do |company| %>

                <div class="cbp-item identity web-design" style="padding: 10px; width: 207px; position: relative;"><div class="cbp-item-wrapper">
                  <div class="cbp-caption">
                    <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap">
                      <img src="<%= company.get_logo(:thumb) %>" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap">
                      <div class="c-masonry-border"></div>
                      <div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter">
                        <div class="cbp-l-caption-body">
                          <%= link_to company, :method=>:get do %>
                              <p class="cbp-singlePage cbp-l-caption-buttonLeft btn c-btn-square c-btn-border-1x c-btn-white c-btn-bold c-btn-uppercase c-btn-block">Les mer</p>
                          <% end %>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <p class="cbp-singlePage cbp-l-grid-masonry-projects-title"><%=link_to company.name, company%></p>
                </div></div>

            <% end %>

          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="c-center">
        <%= will_paginate @companies, page_links: false, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could we get the CSS that you're currently applying? Bonus if we can also get some of the HTML that's actually output to the browser, so that we can replicate the styles here.

Answer (score 0):

Delete this from `#grid-container-fullwidth`: `style="height:1270px"`

Comment: Doesn't work, it just collapses. That's why it's there